# UIViewControllerのサブクラスのカスタムinitでsuper.initを呼べないのは何故ですか？

Tags: swift, ios

```
class HogeVC: UIViewController {
    var id: Int?

    init(id: Int) {
        super.init() // Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'

        self.id = id
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


}
```

上記コード内のコメントにも記載しましたが、

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'

というエラーがでました。

この問題は
`super.init()`を
`super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`に書き換えることで対応できました。

ここで疑問がでました。

- なぜ、`UIViewController`は`super.init()`を呼べないのでしょうか？
- 自分で `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass '....'` を起こすような親クラスを作ることは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ***なぜ、UIViewControllerはsuper.init()を呼べないのでしょうか？***

`UIViewController.init()`はdesignated initializer(指定イニシャライザ、または、指名イニシャライザ、と訳されることが多いようです)ではないからです。

Swiftのイニシャライザには小うるさい規則がいくつもあって、それらは緩いObjective-Cの世界とはうまく動かなかったりするのですが、ここら辺に明記してあります。

[Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216)

> ### Initializer Delegation for Class Types
>
> #### Rule 1
>
> A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its
>   immediate superclass.
>
> ### クラス型の初期化の委譲について
>
> #### 規則1
>
> 指名イニシャライザは直接のスーパークラスの指名イニシャライザのどれかを呼ばなければいけません。

あなたの`init(id:)`には`convenience`と言うキーワードがついていませんから、「指名イニシャライザ」を定義しているものと解釈されます。従って、規則1により、直接のスーパークラスである`UIViewController`の指名イニシャライザをその中で呼ぶ必要があります。

つまり指名イニシャライザ`init(id:)`の定義中では、`UIViewController`の指名イニシャライザである`init(nibName:bundle:)`または`init?(coder:)`(こっちは単なる指名イニシャライザではなく、必須イニシャライザでもありますが)のどちらかを呼んでやらないとエラーになります。

- ***自分で Must call a designated initializer of the superclass '....' を起こすような親クラスを作ることは可能なのでしょうか？***

「`init()`と言うシグニチャーのイニシャライザは存在するが、それは指名イニシャライザではない」と言うクラスを定義すれば、すぐに再現可能です。

```
class MyClass {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "")
    }
}

class DerivedClass: MyClass {
    var id: Int?

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id

        super.init() //-> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'MyClass'
    }
}
```

---

Objective-Cで定義された`NSObject`の子孫クラスでは、Objective-Cの特性上、`NSObject`で定義されている`- (instancetype)init`というイニシャライザ(Swiftに移入されると`init()`)を無かったことには出来ないのですが、多くのクラスで`init()`はドキュメント化されてもいない動作不詳のイニシャライザです。`super.init()`が通用するクラスであっても、その動作がドキュメントで明記されていない限り、呼ばない方が良いでしょう。